# Windows Phone 7 - Bing Maps MVVM Pushpin initialization

Tags: mvvm, windows-phone-7

Does anyone have a good guideline on how to initialize a pushpin on the Bing Maps control?
My current scenario works, but is not 100% correct... let me explain the details:

When I open the page with the Bing Maps control on it, I want the user to be able to push a small button that will show his current location.
To show the current location, I'm using a Pushpin. I'm already adding the Pushpin on the control in the XAML file like this:

```
<map:Pushpin> x:Name="currentLocation" Location="{Binding CurrentLocation}" Content="Me" ManipulationStarted="CurrentLocationPin_ManipulationStarted" </map:Pushpin>
```

Now with this scenario there a some problems!
One, the pushpin is always visible! So how do I go about this? ( I know I can bind the Visibility also to a property and use a bool to visibility converter, but is this the best way to do this? )
Secondly, now I don't initialize the Location in the viewmodel... but for semantic reasons I would love to initialize the default value to Geocoordinate.Unkown ( that way I can use this to do checks when the user tries to do some manipulation before a currentlocation is set ). But when I initialize the pushpin on startup I get following error: "UIElement.Arrange(finalRect) cannot be called with Infinite or NaN values in finalRect.". So my question again :) what is a good guideline to setting up a currentlocation pushpin? ( but do mind that the users has to push a small application bar button before the currentlocation is set )

Comment: Is that really your XAML? It doesn't look valid.

Comment: The XAML is: `<map:Pushpin x:Name="currentLocation" Location="{Binding CurrentLocation}" Visibility="{Binding CurrentLocationVisible}" Background="#003D76" Content="Me" ></map:Pushpin>`

Answer (score 0):

The initialization problem is due to the visibility of the `Pushpin`. If the initial visibility of the `Pushpin` is `Collapsed`, then it won't take part in the arrange pass, so you won't get the error.

If you're using a view model to back this view, then I don't see a problem with exposing a property from the view model that determines whether the `Pushpin` should be visibile or not. Yes you could use a boolean to visibility converter, but you could save some processing by actually exposing a `Visibility` property (which is the approach I've used).

If you're using a command to initiate showing the `Pushpin` from the button push (the [Silverlight Windows Phone Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com) has a behavior to enable hooking up application bar buttons to commands).

Comment: The tip for setting the pushpin visible or not with a visibility property works great :), but even setting the pushpin to Visibility.Collapsed ( with this property ), I still get the error if I try to initialize the pushpin to Geocoordinate.Unknow!

Comment: Hmm that's a shame. In that case, you could initialize the backing field to `GeoCoordinate.Unknown`, but return a valid coordinate in the property getter. That should work.

Comment: Ok that is not what I was looking for... so maybe I'll leave the pushpin off and add it only when the user cliked the locate me button...